# How to get span html witout class ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this html.(I'm new at ajax syntax sory)

```
<div class="select2-container select2" id="s2id_ServiceID-2-1" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
       <span>Select A Service</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I need to control span text != "Select A Service"

I can't add class or id to span

I have another spans on that code

I need to use ajax

I used this to reach span but not working

```
var serviceList = $('.select2 - choice .span');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra spaces and `span`  in the selector - `.select2-choice span`.

```js
var serviceList = $('.select2-choice span');
console.log(serviceList.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select2-container select2" id="s2id_ServiceID-2-1" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
       <span>Select A Service</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: retracted my vote because in edit you've mentioned to remove space in class. and again retracted because you've removed the dot before the span

Comment: @SagarV It's Ok

Comment: I have many span can i get all of them on for it is not working 
console.log(serviceList[i].html());

Comment: `html` will return the first one's. You need o\to iterate over them and for each item use `html`